# Implement a class with inheritance in javascript

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, constructor, super

I am trying to create a javascript class and subclass with the following requirements:

#### Product class

##### Attributes:

1. productId as string datatype;
2. productName as string datatype;

##### Methods:

1. getProductId()  => this method must return product id
2. getProductName()  => this method must return product name

#### DressProduct as a child class of Product

##### Attributes:

1. productSize as number datatype;
2. productType as string datatype;

####Methods:

1. getProductSize()  ==> this method must return product size
2. getProductType()  ==> this method must return product type

This is what I have so far, but I don't think this is the correct implementation to satisfy the output `Product Id: A101 Product Size: 42`

```js
export class Product {
  productId: string
  productName: string

  constructor(public id: string) {
    this.productId = 'A101'
    // this.productName = ''
  }

  getProductId() {
    return this.productId
  }
  getProductName() {
    return this.productName
  }
}

export class DressProduct extends Product {
  productSize: number
  productType: string

  constructor(public id: string, public size: number) {
    super(id)
  }

  getProductSize() {
    return this.productSize
  }
  getProductType() {
    return this.productType
  }
}

let product = new DressProduct('A101', 42)
// Output: Product Id: A101 Product Size: 42
```

Comment: You are using [parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties) as well as regular properties, and are not copying things properly.  Perhaps you should work on just your `Product` class and get that correct first before subclassing it.  Is this just homework or do you have a real use case?  It seems like you haven't quite given a [mcve] since it's not clear how and when the desired output is supposed to appear (it outputs that string *when*?).  Are your class constructors supposed to take arguments for each property?

Comment: If I remove parameter properties and just try to implement this straight, assuming that constructors require all properties to be passed in, then I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBPQzW), but I don't know how the "output" is supposed to be produced.  Is this what you're looking for?  If not, please consider elaborating on what you are trying to achieve.  If it *is* what you're looking for, I can write up an answer, but it would be helpful if you gave some idea of which parts of that need to be explained, since it is a fairly basic example.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Hi, yes, that code snippet did help. My main issue was trying to figure where parameters got passed and how they were set.